# Compare Date including Time part in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a requirement where we need to compare date along with time in SQL server to fetch particular records in that time interval.

Below is the sample code which i am trying and not getting expected results with it -

```
SELECT [VESSEL_ID], [PARTY_ID], [LAST_UPDATE_DATE]
FROM [dbo].[VS_VESSEL_PARTY_DETAILS] 
WHERE [VESSEL_ID] = 19125 AND LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= Convert(datetime, '2018-12-17 13:21:02.710') AND LAST_UPDATE_DATE <= Convert(datetime, '2018-12-17 18:21:02.710') AND [END_DATE]  IS NULL ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE_DATE DESC
```

In above example, i am expecting to get all the records in the particular time interval.

Can someone help me to correct this query or suggest a better solution?

Thank you very much
-Sameer

Comment: Use `BETWEEN ... AND`

Comment: What is the issue you're experiencing? Your query is correct as written, unless, perhaps, `LAST_UPDATE_DATE` is not a datetime data type.

Comment: See, also, [What Do BETWEEN And The Devil Have In Common](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: @EricBrandt: Every concept in computer science has a [this concept considered harmful] article attached to it *somewhere* on the internet.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, that's absolutely true (and a pretty funny observation). I've just seen a lot of the mistaken assumptions that Aaron notes in that one happen in real life, so my personal bias is toward explicit conditions rather than `BETWEEN`. Full disclosure, I'm alone on an island in my current shop on that bias.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Between should help, with it all in parenthesis.

```
SELECT [VESSEL_ID], [PARTY_ID], [LAST_UPDATE_DATE]
    FROM [dbo].[VS_VESSEL_PARTY_DETAILS] 
    WHERE [VESSEL_ID] = 19125 
    AND LAST_UPDATE_DATE between( Convert(datetime, '2018-12-17 13:21:02.710') 
    AND  Convert(datetime, '2018-12-17 18:21:02.710') )
    AND [END_DATE]  IS NULL ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE_DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT [VESSEL_ID], [PARTY_ID], [LAST_UPDATE_DATE]
FROM [dbo].[VS_VESSEL_PARTY_DETAILS] 
WHERE [VESSEL_ID] = 19125 AND
      LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= Convert(datetime, '2018-12-17 13:21:02.710') AND 
      LAST_UPDATE_DATE <= Convert(datetime, '2018-12-17 18:21:02.710') AND
      [END_DATE]  IS NULL
ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE_DATE DESC;
```

Nothing is wrong with the query.  If you are not receiving any rows, then no rows match the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare LAST_UPDATE_DATE to be less_than_or_equal and at the same time greater_than_or_equal to the same value, ultimately it is an equivalent of simple equal.

So your statement should have been following:

```
SELECT [VESSEL_ID], [PARTY_ID], [LAST_UPDATE_DATE]
  FROM [dbo].[VS_VESSEL_PARTY_DETAILS] 
  WHERE [VESSEL_ID] = 19125 AND LAST_UPDATE_DATE = Convert(datetime, '2018-12-17 13:21:02.710') 
  ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE_DATE DESC
```

However, since you may not know exact time down to milliseconds you may need to use a range of different values, slightly different.

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DATETIME = Convert(datetime, '2018-12-17 13:21:02.700')
DECLARE @DateTo DATETIME = Convert(datetime, '2018-12-17 13:21:02.720')
-- note that above times are 20ms apart

SELECT [VESSEL_ID], [PARTY_ID], [LAST_UPDATE_DATE]
  FROM [dbo].[VS_VESSEL_PARTY_DETAILS] 
  WHERE [VESSEL_ID] = 19125 AND LAST_UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN @DayFrom AND @DayTo
  ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE_DATE DESC
```

BTW, its better to take out any static value calculation out of SELECT statement, so it doesn't calculate it on each row.

Comment: The times are not the same in the OP's question, just the dates.